# TPLink UBS wifi adapter (Archer T2U Plus) on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: wireless, 22.10, tp-link

This is a very weird problem. I had this working on my ubuntu 2 years ago and then changed house and went from verizon to specturm. Now the wifi does not work. I tried reinstalling, a bunch of times. I can see visible networks but it would not connect and work. Wired works fine. I am new to this forum so please let me know what to try on my command line for diagnostics and I will be happy to post it here.

Comment: please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit your question to include results from the wireless script